# Adding Days to a Date with PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to add a certain amount of days to a set date in PHP. However, all of the code I use is not working. Here is the code I am currently experiencing problems with:

```
echo date("2013-12-01", strtotime("+7 days"));
```

I wanting to add 7 days to the date above. When I echo out this code, it just prints '2013-12-01'. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's how you do it with [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$datetime = new DateTime("2013-12-01");
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

or

```
$datetime = new DateTime("2013-12-01");
$datetime->modify('+7 days');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date_add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php) function:

```
$date = date_create('2013-12-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

[This will output `2013-12-08`](http://ideone.com/Q9z08P)

Comment: I think he SHOULD use that function instead of messing with strings.

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this:

```
$NewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2013-12-01" . " +7 days"));
echo $NewDate;
```