# Adding days to current date only once

Tags: php, date

I want to add particular days to current date. where days are taking from database field. It adds to the present date properly but at next day, date is going to update to the present date again.so how to keep date unchanged. It should take only once in PHP

```
$day= $cur["Days"];
 if(($cur["Days"]) == 0){
   $new = '';
 } else {
    $Date = date('20y-m-d');
    $new = date("20y-m-d", strtotime($Date . ' + ' . $day . ' days'));
 }
```

> input if $day=1,$day+$new

> output= jan19,this is the output of one row and my problem is it should remain as it is for this row but now for next day it is going to change to jan20 that should not happen

Comment: Please explain with an input and expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Days to a Date with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959959/adding-days-to-a-date-with-php)

Comment: use a session counter for it. if counter > 1 that means you need not add now, otherwise update it.

Comment: could you please demonstrate an example here @Anant-Alivetodie

Comment: Do you have any idea @Nikhil Sawant ?